# How to disable certificate validation in java

Tags: java, ssl, network-programming, certificate, ssl-certificate

I need to disable Java certificate validation for testing only. So I understand the risk. I used the following tutorial: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-fix-certificate-problem-in-HTTPS.html

So the code is:

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class Cert {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    /*
     *  fix for
     *    Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
     *       sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
     *           PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
     *               unable to find valid certification path to requested target
     */
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
       new X509TrustManager() {
          public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
          }

          public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {  }

          public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {  }

       }
    };

    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

    // Create all-trusting host name verifier
    HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
          return true;
        }
    };
    // Install the all-trusting host verifier
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
    /*
     * end of the fix
     */

    URL url = new URL("https://www.nakov.com:2083/");
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
    while (true) {
      int ch = reader.read();
      if (ch==-1) {
        break;
      }
      System.out.print((char)ch);
    }
      }
    }
```

I still get the following error. Can any body help ?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://www.nakov.com:2083/
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1615)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at MainProject.Cert.main(Cert.java:56)
```

Comment: I have a similar code but when I run my app it gives me error saying : java.lang.classcastexception: java.lang.string cannot be  cast to java.lang.boolean. I believe that this error is coming from the verify(String, SSLSession) method where it return a boolean but due to some reason in my case it return a null? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The "fix" and the exception appear unrelated: The fix disables verification of the server's certificate by the client while the exception indicates that the server deemed the client not authorized to access that URL.

Comment: But when I add the URL to my browser I can access it. The only thing is that Firefox warns me against the self signed certificate.

Comment: Then I'd inspect the http request firefox sends (for instance with firebug's network tab) to spot the difference (a cookie? the user-agent header? a different http-proxy? ...?).

Answer (score 3):

This won't fix the problem. The 401 was transmitted over HTTPS and SSL, so the certificates are working perfectly.

In any case I strongly recommend you don't do this. You don't want different code executing in test and production. There is a strong risk the test code will leak into production and compromise security. And there is no point in testing insecure code.

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother disabling it in your code, you can just add the certificate to your testing machines truststore and be 100% sure you don't ship a build with the check disabled.

Comment: I need to do this programatically.

Comment: @JuryA Why? Why would you ever want to write code that is conditionally insecure? Don't do this.

Comment: I have to do that too because it's software I'm writing for several clients that will connect to their own servers with all different certificates. I don't really care about the certificate because the link is entirely trusted.

Comment: Both sides of this argument are actually right - while it's right to ensure that the certificates are valid, the developers will have to manage certificates continuously - simple if it's only a couple, but what happens when it proliferates?  What happens when 2-way SSL comes into play?  Client certificates have to be installed on servers too... this can get out of hand.  On the flip side, if there is an integration environment which has genuine certificates deployed and there is automated testing against new deployments, then everyone is a winner.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, the error 401 means that you really established the SSL connection, sent your request and were served back this 401 error. So your SSL code is fine.

When you open this page in the browser, are you getting a username/password prompt ? Maybe auto-login ? If this is the case, I would say that your code is missing this basic authentication or similar.